# XSLT, how to alternate key() function for a lookup table with a numeric loop

Tags: xml, for-loop, xslt, key

I've made a lookup table to transform the name of a Month in the corresponding number of the Month.

It's some like:

```
<lookup:months>
    <lookup:month><lookup:nr>1</lookup:nr> <lookup:name>January</lookup:name></lookup:month>
    <lookup:month><lookup:nr>2</lookup:nr> <lookup:name>February</lookup:name></lookup:month> 
    <lookup:month><lookup:nr>3</lookup:nr> <lookup:name>March</lookup:name></lookup:month>
```

It works, starting from data like:

```
<Months>
    <Month>March</Month>
```

Transformed to:

```
<li class="active">3</li>
```

But in this (and in all) case I would like to get a final markup like:

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li class="active">3</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
<li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
```

How can I get this result?

I suppose I have to use something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 12">
    [pseudo code] when key match, value of "key(args)/lookup:nr"
    otherwise value-of select="."
```

I've tried but I can't get it to work...

Comment: Do you use XSLT 2.0 (as `1 to 12` suggests)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Martin Honnen surely is the most polished and brief, but if you want to use a lookup-table system with key() that can be extended to other parameters, I managed to find this tested solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <!-- lookup table -->
 <xsl:variable name="months-lookup-table">
    <month><nr>1</nr> <name>January</name></month>
    <month><nr>2</nr> <name>February</name></month> 
    <month><nr>3</nr> <name>March</name></month> 
    <month><nr>4</nr> <name>April</name></month> 
    <month><nr>5</nr> <name>May</name></month> 
    <month><nr>6</nr> <name>June</name></month> 
    <month><nr>7</nr>  <name>July</name></month> 
    <month><nr>8</nr>  <name>August</name></month> 
    <month><nr>9</nr>  <name>September</name></month> 
    <month><nr>10</nr> <name>October</name></month> 
    <month><nr>11</nr> <name>November</name></month> 
    <month><nr>12</nr> <name>December</name></month> 
 </xsl:variable>

  <!-- key to convert name month (in month number) -->
  <xsl:key name="from-name-of-month-to-nr-of-month" match="month" use="name"/>



  <xsl:template match="Months">


        <!-- save the selected month context -->
        <xsl:variable name="selected-month" select="Month"/>

        <!-- loop all months name in the lookup table, THIS is the active loop -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$months-lookup-table/month">

           <!-- print the current looped month transformed from name to number, if the current looped month ($month-in-loop) name matches with the month name in XML source ($selected-month), add  an attribute of "active" -->
                <xsl:element name="li">
                    <xsl:if test="$selected-month = name">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('from-name-of-month-to-nr-of-month', name, $months-lookup-table)/nr"/>
                </xsl:element>

         </xsl:for-each>        


  </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEwa/2

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one month value in your input but want to generate a list of all month numbers then, assuming XSLT 2.0, it suffices to use

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="months"
  select="'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Months">
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="Month"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to 12">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="$months[current()] = $month">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuQm